# How to account for a partial derivative term in an Operator, in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, topological-quantum-computing

The crystal momentum p1 = h bar * k and this is defined in the reciprocal momentum, I am guessing this p1 is not a real momentum since the reciprocal space is an imaginary space which we use for studying diffraction phenomena. Also, p1 is a vector, not an operator

The momentum in the momentum space (just like the position in the position space) has its eigenvectors which will span the momentum space, and its given by P|p> = p|p>. Also, the momentum vector associated with a wave vector k is given by - p_vector = h bar * k

Also we know that in the position basis, the momentum operator is -i * h bar * (del operator), and this is derived from differentiating avg of x.

I am trying to find (i * del/del kx) in terms of operator. I am not sure if I can do this. My initial attempt in doing this was to swap the kx and X since kx is the equivalent of X in position basis, in the momentum space, but seems like its incorrect. However, when I used this in my code, I was getting one of the two plots correct. Another method, what I did was to equate p_vector to the P operator in the momentum space, and arrived at this relation - kx = -i * del/del x. I guess this is also wrong because we cant equate a vector to an oeprator [Operator acts on a vector]. I am not sure how to proceed with this (unsure if we can even do this).

I need to find this since I am trying to find winding number using quantum computing technique as mentioned in this PRL (https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06086 - Digital Simulation of Topological Matter using Programmable Quantum Processors). So, for this, (atleast from what I have understood is that) they introduce a displacement operator since its avg over a long time limit is equivalent to the Berry phase and winding number is berry phase mod 2Pi. The displacement operator in the momentum space is expressed as (i * del/del kx) Pauli Z operator. This acts on the wavefunction to give the required result. I know that I cant do partial derivative wrt kx, unless Pauli Z is operated on the wavefunction, and (i * del/del kx) differentials the transformed wavefunction.

Any assistance is appreciated.

I posted this on Physics forum too, but not sure if its more relevant there than in Quantum Computing Forum.

Edit: I realized that vectors can be operators too, like the divergence operator.